# Stochastic convex (conave) functions vs. convex (concave) function

Tags: probability, convex-optimization

Can someone help me understand the difference beween **stochastic** convex (conave) functions and convex (concave) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition is surely explained in the book or lecture note you're reading. A stochastic function is a function from $\Omega$ to a function space. Here is an example : let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Then the following defines a random function : 
$$ F : \omega \longrightarrow \Big( f_{\omega} : x \to X(\omega) + x \Big)$$

A stochastic convex function is a random variable taking values in a space of convex functions. In the example given above, $F$ would be a stochastic convex function if for every $\omega$, $f_{\omega}$ is convex.